# Laravel view doesn't show anything

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

so i am new in Laravel, i follow this [Tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) but when i check my application i got **IP-TEST-NGINX**, for more details this is my code,

**First my index action :**

```
class ServiceController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // get all the services
    $services = Service::all();

    // load the view and pass the services
    return View::make('services.index')->with('service', $services);
}
```

**Second my route :**

```
Route::resource('services', 'ServiceController');
```

**Then my model :**

```
<?php

class Service extends Eloquent
{

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $table = 'services';

}
```

**Finally my view :**

```
 @foreach($services as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->domain }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->service_name }}</td>
```

When i go to the url : `http://localhost:8080/laravel/services` i got the error **IP-TEST-NGINX**, any help please :)

Comment: Forget Laravel for a sec, does a vanilla PHP script load fine? i.e. `test.php` `<?php echo 'It works';`

Comment: Yes when i add a info.php in my Laravel folder and i check it with http://localhost:8080/laravel/info.php it works fine !!

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the view with `service` instead of `services`

should be:

```
return View::make('services.index')->with('services', $services);
```

also, depending on if you are running a virtual host, you may need to hit `http://localhost:8080/laravel/public/services`

Comment: try this in your controller to make sure you are hitting it: change `return View::make('services.index')->with('services', $services);` to `return "hello world!"`. that will let you know if you are hitting your controller.

Comment: you're right even if i tried hello world i got the same error !!,should i put something in my public folder ?

Comment: you shouldnt need to mess with `/public`. It appears that your serving environment isnt setup quite right. Are you using laravel 4? If so, it comes with a built in server that will ease the pain of setting up a local environment greatly. try opening up command prompt/terminal, navigating to the root directory, and running `php artisan serve`.